# C - checking for string equality

Tags: c, string, arguments

I keep getting an error after running the program.
The error is "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" and I get a note.

```
note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
 extern int strcmp (const char *__s1, const char *__s2)
```

This is my code:

```
int main()
{
  char cmdline[100];
  printf ("esp> ");
  fgets( cmdline, sizeof( cmdline ), stdin );

  char *args[4] = { NULL };
  char *pchcaus;

  pchcaus = strtok (cmdline," ");

  int i = 0;
  while (pchcaus != NULL)
  {
    args[i++] = pchcaus;
    pchcaus = strtok (NULL, " ");
  }

  char* command = args[0];
  char* argumentOne = args[1];
  char* argumentTwo = args[2];
  char* input = { "quit" };

  printf ("%s", command);    // this prints "quit"

  if (strcmp(command, input) == 0) {  // this is not working. why ?
    printf("Bye.\n" );
  }

  return 0;
}
```

And if I type quit it returns "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". Everything else is working but last if statement. The one that compares the strings

Comment: Either you get a compiler error (which the `strcmp` note is about) or you get a crash (the segmentation fault). You can't really haver both from the same program, since the program needs to be built without errors for you to be able to run it and get the crash.

Comment: as far as i can see you try to implicitely cast `(char**) {"quit"}` to `char* input`. try removing those curly braces and it should be a `char*`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg i'd suspect it's only a compiler warning (which `gcc` should throw if it's the error I suspect it to be, see comment above)

Comment: `cmdline` is not defined. There is no `main()` function. Please provide the code you are actually compiling instead of a subset of it.

Comment: also maybe try to get a hint at what call's crashing by running `gdb`'s backtrace…

Comment: What string is entered after the prompt?

Comment: I enter string     quit

Comment: You should extract a minimal but complete example before posting here. Your code is neither complete nor minimal. That said, the error suggests you are passing a `char` instead of a `char*` or `char const*` to `strcmp()`. BTW: Your last sentence seems to be incomplete.

Comment: also PLEASE take a look at your edit's preview before always submitting wrongly formatted posts…

Comment: Try replacing `char* input = { "quit" };` with `char input[] = "quit";`.
`.

Comment: I'd rather replace the whole use of this `input` variable (which is not input!) with the string literal `"quit"`, as that would make the code shorter and more readable.

Answer (score 2):

the root of the problem is two fold:

1)  this initialization is less than ideal:

```
char* input = {"quit"};
```

suggest:

```
char* input = "quit";
```

2) the `fgets()` function  inputs the trailing `<newline>`.   That `<newline>` needs to be trimmed

The actual result of entering 'quit' is:

```
"quit\n"
```

suggest, after the call to `fgets()` insert this:

```
char *NewLine = NULL;
if( NULL != (NewLine = strstr( cmdline, "\n" ) ) )
{
     *NewLine = '\0';
}
```

The code should also be checking (!=NULL) the returned value from `fgets()` to assure the input operation was successful

Comment: You are right, a lot of checking is missing from the code. +1 for the fgets() getting the '\n' as well...

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem is that `input` should be defined as `char* input[] = { "quit" };` and the condition should be `strcmp(command, input[0]) == 0`.

Or `input` should be defined as `char* input = "quit";` and the condition can remain as in your example.

In your example `input` is declared as `char**`, but used as `char*` in `strcmp`. This is stated in the warning...

But although it is really a bug, I cannot explain the `Segmentation fault` error. This means that the code tries to read (or write) to a wrong address (a code not in your user address space). But in your case input is just a pointer to a pointer on the stack (which points to an char array in the initialized data segment, which contains five bytes: 'q', 'u', 'i', 't', '\0'). So I have to think it over...

Comment: this line: `strcmp(command, input[0]) == 0` is not correct, as the second parameter also has to be a `char *` and the second parameter is only a single char, not a pointer to a NUL terminated array of char.

Comment: @user3629249 `char* input[]` is `char**`, so `input[0]` is `char*`.

Comment: in the code posted by the OP, the variable input is defined as `char* input = { "quit" };`,  so it is not `char **input[]`

Comment: @user3629249 ...and what is the first line of my answer? :)